# How can I load the rails environment from within a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I need to require config/environment.rb.  How can I do this from within a gem?

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a new project to get the `config/environment.rb` file and all other support files like environment folder, app, etc.,

When you create a new project it should automatically created these files. You don't need to create it manually.

Comment: This does not answer the original question.